# If $ P $ is $U(0,1)$ show that $Y = -2\log(P)$ is $\chi^2$

Tags: probability, statistics

I also need to find the degrees of freedom. I started like this:

$$Pr(Y \le y) = Pr(-2\log(P) \le y) = Pr(P>e^{-y/2})=1- e^{-y/2}$$

I don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: write down CDF of $\chi^2$ with degree $2$.